# How does this regex work and how do i make it repeat only 5 times?

Tags: regex

What does this regex do? i know it replaces the filename (but not extension)

```
    Regex r = new Regex("(?<!\\.[0-9a-z]*)[0-9]");
    return r.Replace(sz, "#");
```

How do i make it only repeat 5 times? to make it convert
"1111111111.000" to "11111#####.000" ?

Comment: What is this being used for? Knowing how it is used will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I havent' tried this but</del> **Have** tried it, **works**: how about changing the general pattern to use a positive lookahead instead? That way, it should work:

```
[0-9a-z](?=[0-9a-z]{0,4}\.)
```

Basically, this finds any (alphanumeric) character followed by up to four other alphanumeric characters and a period. This might just work to match the last five characters in front of the period consecutively. It's hellishly inefficient though, and it only works with engines that allow variable-width lookahead patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the asterisk after the closing bracket to "`{5}`" (no quotes). This depends a bit on your regex environment's feature set, but that is a common syntax.

Comment: That breaks it (the ext now becomes ###).

Answer (score 0):

The regex matches a character (0 to 9) that is not preceded by a dot then any number of 0 to 9 or a to z's.

The replace line is responsible for the multi replacements. So you want to use the Replace method the has an [extra parameter count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332131(VS.71).aspx).

so the code would look like:

```
 Regex r = new Regex("(?<!\\.[0-9a-z]*)[0-9]");
 return r.Replace(sz, "#", 5);
```

Comment: Not tested, but this should actually replace the first 5 digits, thus giving you '#####1111.000' which is not what you want. So go with Konrad's solution.